# Kotlin For loop start from a given index

Tags: kotlin

I want to start a For loop from a given index
in Java you can easily write

```
for (int i = startingIndex; i < items.size(); i++)
```

how to to do that in Kotlin?
I know how to write a for loop in Kotlin

my example

I want to iterate over an array of strings but the start position is 3, not iterating over a `Range` the iteration will be over a collection of items

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops

Comment: @JBNizet this link does not show how to start from a given index!!!!

Comment: Yes it does: `for (i in 1..3) {`. If items is a list, you should iterate on a subList using a foreach loop

Comment: @JBNizet can you tell how it does? I want to iterate over an array of strings but the start position is 3 for example, your example always starts from the specified Range not a collection of items

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For iterating from the start item till the last, you can use something like this:

```
for (i in startingIndex until items.size) {
    //apply your logic
}
```

Comment: I know how to iterate and use a For Loop my question was clear, how to start from a given index!!!!!

Comment: @tamtom Okay now you've edited the question, I guess I got it. I edited the answer and see if `until` was the one that you were looking for.

Comment: Here 'i' is a value/item of items list, so how to get the index inside this for loop? How can we use withIndex() with this?

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to drop first `n` elements and use `forEach` from there:

```kotlin
val l = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
l.drop(1).forEach { println(it) } // prints "2, 3, 4"
```

Comment: It wouldn't be Kotlin if there wasn't 5 obscure ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: But bear in mind, that `drop` allocates a new list

Answer (score 4):

Instead of iterating over the items in your array, you can iterate over the indices and access the array by index. Here's a simple example.

```
val otherStrings = arrayOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
for (i in 3..otherStrings.size-1)
    println(otherStrings[i])
```

This iterates from starting index 3 to the last index (which is `size - 1`)

Answer (score 3):

If the function is repeated several times you could do this:

1. Create an extension function

```
    List<String>.startByIndex(startingIndex : Int){
       for(index in startingIndex until this.size){
  
         //apply common logic
    
       }
    }
```

2. call the extension function from your string list

```
var startIndex : Int = 3 // example
items.startByIndex(startIndex)
```

P.S. : If, for example, the extension function must always return a string as output, you have to change everything like this:

```
    List<String>.startByIndex(startingIndex : Int) : String {
       for(index in startingIndex until this.size){

         var result : String

         //apply common logic and instantiate var result

         return result
    
       }
    }




    var startIndex : Int = 3 // example
    var result : String = items.startByIndex(startIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator ..< like this, this will be clean and simple:

```
for (i in index..<items.size) {
    //apply your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I want to be one of the cool kids also, let me throw this into the hat:

```
fun Iterable<Number>.except(vararg values: Number): Iterable<Number> =
    this@except.filter { !values.contains(it) }.asIterable()
```

and:

```
fun Iterable<Number>.except(range: Iterable<Number>): Iterable<Number> = 
    this@except.filter { !range.contains(it) }.asIterable()
```

Use it like:

```
for (i in (1..10).except(3, 5, 7)) {
    // ....
}
```

or like this:

```
for (i in (1..10).except(3..7)) {
    // ....
}
```

Test it:

```
  @Test
  fun testExceptSpecific() {
    val except = (1..10).except(3, 5, 7)
    assertEquals(7, except.count())
    assertEquals(1, except.first())
    assertEquals(10, except.last())
    assertEquals(1, except.elementAt(0))
    assertEquals(2, except.elementAt(1))
    assertEquals(4, except.elementAt(2))
    assertEquals(6, except.elementAt(3))
    assertEquals(8, except.elementAt(4))
    assertEquals(9, except.elementAt(5))
    assertEquals(10, except.elementAt(6))
  }

  @Test
  fun testExceptRange() {
    val except = (1..10).except(3..7)
    assertEquals(5, except.count())
    assertEquals(1, except.first())
    assertEquals(10, except.last())
    assertEquals(1, except.elementAt(0))
    assertEquals(2, except.elementAt(1))
    assertEquals(8, except.elementAt(2))
    assertEquals(9, except.elementAt(3))
    assertEquals(10, except.elementAt(4))
  }
```